# check if value is between two ranges - if true exclude row

Tags: matlab

I have a numerical array that consists of several columns, where I have

```
i=3.02:0.00008:3.098;
j= 3.020005:0.00008:3.098005;
```

and want to check in column 6 if the values lie between the values of `i` and `j`, so in the first case this would be between `3.02` and `3.020005`. If this is true then I want to exclude all of the other values in the same row.

Comment: and what is your problem?, what have you tried so far?

Comment: the issue is with the range of numbers in i and j - I'm not sure the most appropriate syntax when trying to create an IF statement. If it were just one value I could use indexing however here I am not sure.

Comment: Try it adn if you are stuck ask for hep. But try it

Comment: Going with the indexing idea I have tried to use index =  (merged(merged(:,6) > i && merged(:,6) < j)); but this gives Error using  > 
Matrix dimensions must agree. although the dimensions are the same